# Why does backbone fetch not work for me

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to solve issue with backbone fetch. I am getting 'Failed to fetch!' in my console.

I think it is not issue connected with same origin policy because JSON is returned from server and according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is valid

```
[{"name":"Spanish A1"},{"name":"Spanish A2"}]
```

Code in gist: https://gist.github.com/KonradMasalski/bfaac7d481d890ca5c54

Update - code

```
var Fishe = {};

Fishe.Deck = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});

Fishe.DeckCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Fishe.Deck,
    url: 'http://fishes.localhost/deck.json',
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        console.log('syncing');
        var params = _.extend({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: this.url,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                this.model.set($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText));
            }
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params).done(function () {
            console.log('finished')
        });
    }
});


Fishe.data = {};
Fishe.data.decks = new Fishe.DeckCollection();

Fishe.data.decks.fetch({
    success: function () {
        console.log(Fishe.data.decks.toJSON());
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Failed to fetch!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Returned content-type is application/json. Response argument has following information: readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "load"

Comment: So why in browser console I am seeing proper json which content-type application/json. But in response obtained by backbone it is "load"?

Comment: If you're getting a 200, then it's a parserError

Comment: To figure out a little more about the error, try:

error: function (model, response, option) {
    console.log(model);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(options.error.arguments[1]);
};

Comment: Yes, it was parse error. Thank you. Now I return empty JSON. Backbone should deal with that? But still I get parse error. I even used my own parse function on collection ( parse: function(response) { console.log("Inside Parse"); } ) but it is never called.

Comment: @konradmas are you returning empty JSON or empty response (204 no content)?

Comment: empty json array: []
response code 200

Comment: This is not an answer to my problem with backbone fetch but if anyone is curious: to get things done I switched to Angular.JS and I drop JSONP in favor of CORS